# Problema quando tento importar meus próprios módulos em Lua (not found)

Tags: lua, importação

No arquivo main.lua:

```lua
local calculadora = {
  somar = function(x, y)
    return x + y
  end
}

function calculadora.multiplicar(x, y)
  return x * y
end

return calculadora
```

No arquivo CopyOfmain.lua

```lua
local calculadora = require("calculadora")

print(calculadora.somar(1, 1))
```

[image: captura de tela do projeto]

erro:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.naef.jnlua.LuaRuntimeException: ..._64\workspace\criando bilbiotecas\src\CopyOfmain.lua:1: module 'calculadora' not found:
    no field package.preload['calculadora']
    no file '.\calculadora.lua'
    no file 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_251\bin\lua\calculadora.lua'
    no file 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_251\bin\lua\calculadora\init.lua'
    no file 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_251\bin\calculadora.lua'
    no file 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_251\bin\calculadora\init.lua'
    no file 'C:\Users\lidio\Downloads\org.eclipse.ldt.product-win32.win32.x86_64\workspace\criando bilbiotecas\src\calculadora.lua'
    no file 'C:\Users\lidio\Downloads\org.eclipse.ldt.product-win32.win32.x86_64\workspace\criando bilbiotecas\src\calculadora\init.lua'
    no file 'C:\Users\lidio\Downloads\org.eclipse.ldt.product-win32.win32.x86_64\workspace\criando bilbiotecas\src\calculadora.luac'
    no file 'C:\Users\lidio\Downloads\org.eclipse.ldt.product-win32.win32.x86_64\workspace\criando bilbiotecas\src\calculadora\init.luac'
    no file '.\calculadora.dll'
    no file '.\calculadora51.dll'
    no file 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_251\bin\calculadora.dll'
    no file 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_251\bin\calculadora51.dll'
    no file 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_251\bin\clibs\calculadora.dll'
    no file 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_251\bin\clibs\calculadora51.dll'
    no file 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_251\bin\loadall.dll'
    no file 'C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_251\bin\clibs\loadall.dll'
    at com.naef.jnlua.LuaState.lua_pcall(Native Method)
    at com.naef.jnlua.LuaState.call(LuaState.java:555)
    at org.eclipse.ldt.support.lua51.internal.interpreter.JNLua51Launcher.run(JNLua51Launcher.java:128)
    at org.eclipse.ldt.support.lua51.internal.interpreter.JNLua51Launcher.main(JNLua51Launcher.java:143)
```

Coloquei o script no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@GustavoGLD/calculadora#calc.lua). Lá também está dando erro

Comment: Testei aqui e para conseguir fazer funcionar eu renomei o arquivo `CopyOfmain.lua` para `calculadora.lua`

Comment: @CodigodeSenior para mim continua dando erro, coloquei o script no site [repl.it](https://repl.it/@GustavoGLD/calculadora#calc.lua) e até lá da erro

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado Agora eu entendi. Testei agora e deu certo! Obrigado

Comment: Coloquei como resposta o comentário, @GustavoGLD

Answer (score 4):

Pela [documentação](https://www.lua.org/pil/8.1.html), você passa `require("name-of-file")`.

Ao chamar `require "lili"`, ele procurará pelos seguintes arquivos:

- `lili`
- `lili.lua`
- `c:\windows\lili`
- `/usr/local/lua/lili/lili.lua`

No seu exemplo, o `require` é chamado passando como argumento "calculadora", porém não tem nenhum arquivo chamado `calculadora`, `calculadora.lua` ou qualquer coisa do gênero.

Answer (score 2):

Deu erro porque você tentou dar require na função ao invés do modulo, você deve fazer como está abaixo:

```lua
local Module = require("CopyOfmain")
local calculadora = Module.calculadora

print(calculadora.somar(1, 1))
```